# using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE to take picture and setImageBitmap to display it

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview

**EDIT i updated the code to reflect changes suggested in both answers, unfortunately, now my app force closes. the error is listed at the bottom**

this is my camera/picture class in its entirety (except for `import`s) this class is supposed to take a picture, display it to the screen, and let another class have the string path of the picture for use as an attachment.
it takes the picture fine, it emails the picture fine, but i cannot figure out how to make it display the picture after its taken. i know there is some sloppy code in there (like in the the `onActivityResult`) but everything except

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_string);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

works great, so I am very interested in finding a solution. any other advice you have on how to clean this up would also be more than welcome, this was just sort of hobbled together from multiple different sources.

```
public class LooksLike extends Activity
    {       
    Button camera;
    Intent intent;
    static String image_string;
    ImageView imageview;
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lookslike);
        camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera);
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.debris_view);
        camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
            public void onClick(View v)
                {
                takePhoto();
                }
            });
        }

    public void takePhoto()
        {
        intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(this)) ); 
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_string);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }

    private File getTempFile(Context context)
        {
        File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getPackageName() );
        if(!path.exists())
            path.mkdir();
        return new File(path, "debris.jpg");
        }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
        switch(requestCode)
            {
            case 1:
            final File file = getTempFile(this);
            try
                {
                Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file) );
                image_string = Uri.fromFile(file).toString();
                Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_string),
                    getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels,
                    getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels, 
                    true);
                imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.debris_view);
              imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
                }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file not found exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            catch (IOException e)
                {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ioexception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

also, here is my xml file:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView  
        android:id="@+id/debris_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:padding="12dip"
        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:text="would you like to take a new debris picture?"
        />
</merge>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need move these 2 lines into onActivityResult():

```
case 1:
    final File file = getTempFile(this);
    try {
        Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file) );
        image_string = Uri.fromFile(file).toString();
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_string);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        ...
```

Code in `takePhoto()` will be executed immediately after `startActivityForResult()` (i.e. it will not wait finishing called activity). Processing result must be done in `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: oh that did seem promising, and obviously it was a start, but im still getting a black screen and not photo. ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_string);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

from `takePhoto` to

```
 try
                        {
                        Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file) );
                        image_string = Uri.fromFile(file).toString();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_string);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
                        }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
```

Comment: the picture is much larger than my screen size but i thought `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` would deal with that.

Comment: Not sure: never used scaleType before. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29: you should be able to force the scale to match your screen. You may have to do some aspect ratio math, but shouldn't be terrible.

Answer (score 0):

You're loading in an image that is probably just too big.
Downscale the image you want to show on screen to a smaller size and it should be fine. The logcat should show something helpfull about it.