# Can't upload image capture from camera android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to write a small code that allows me to send picture directly after taking it from the camera, i want to send pict from capture in camera but never sucess, i'm always get message "Something went wrong"
There is the code

```
public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[] {"Galery", "Foto"};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserProfileActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Pilih");
            builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == 0) {
                        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);

                    } else if (which == 1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                        //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                    }
                }
            });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                RoundedImageViewUtil imgView = (RoundedImageViewUtil) findViewById(R.id.profile);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(photo);

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgPath));
                String fileNameSegments[] = imgPath.split("/");
                fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];
                params.put("filename", fileName);

            } else if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                RoundedImageViewUtil imgView = (RoundedImageViewUtil) findViewById(R.id.profile);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgPath));
                String fileNameSegments[] = imgPath.split("/");
                fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];
                params.put("filename", fileName);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Intead of

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

try

```
Uri imageUri = (Uri)data.getData();
```

and then from uri get your image bitmap.

Comment: Error in imgView.setImageBitmap(photo);

Comment: You have to implement logic for getting bitmap from imageuri, thats why its giving error.

Comment: Uri imageUri = (Uri)data.getData();
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
                RoundedImageViewUtil imgView = (RoundedImageViewUtil) findViewById(R.id.profile);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap()` will bring you a thumbnail; to access the full-size image, you need **BitmapFactory**, see *[using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE to take picture and setImageBitmap to display it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6231724/192373)*

Comment: You need to use code which you added in your last comment which can get you path of image from which you can fetch bitmap.